# Getting image size of a specific CSS class using Selenium or PIL in Python

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I want to calculate the size of some images in Python. But I'm trying to automate it to only find the sizes images of certain classes. I'm new to PIL. Is there a way to, after defining url, also define the CSS class/name/id?

When I did some search there was Selenium that had some functionality for finding CSS elements by id/class/name. But with that is there a way to "connect" the data(image) inside those tags to PIL in a way for them to work together?

Comment: Why do you need to use PIL? You can simply get value of `img` `width` and `height` attributes

Comment: Yup, just realized that now :p  it was so simple, thanks!

Comment: Then since the question and solution have nothing to do with PIL, they use Selenium, please remove PIL from the title, body and tags.

Answer (score 1):

Oops just answering my own question here, I could do this in Selenium:

```
img_height = driver.find_element_by_name("someName").value_of_css_property("height")
img_width = driver.find_element_by_name("someName").value_of_css_property("width")
```

and multiply.